# React Native Filtering An Array Of Objects takes long time or variable is not updated

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter, use-state

I am trying to updated component in react native using a **useState()** hook.

Here is the code.

```
let myHoursList: any;
        myHoursList = hoursList.filter(interval => {
            let start = moment(interval.startTime, "HH:mm")
            let end = moment(interval.endTime, "HH:mm")
            let to = moment(timeLapses[0].closeTime, "HH:mm")
            let from = moment(timeLapses[0].openTime, "HH:m")
            return from <= start && end <= to
        })
setCustomHourList(myHoursList);
```

this function runs when component is mounted. Then when user changes date it re runs again..
But issue is when user changes date for the first time  **myHoursList** variable stays same..
But when the function runs again for 2nd time **myHoursList** variable changes and shows the updated values.

I think the problem is that the filter takes long time as the array has more than 50 **objects**

So is there a way I can fix this How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

```
const [customHourList, setCustomHourList] = useState([])



 const getHoursList = async (day: number) => {
        const response = await fetch(`SERVER_URL`);
        const json = await response.json();
         if (!json.error) {
        let timeLapses = json.result[0].schedule[day].lapses.map(function (time: any) {
            let closeTime = `${time.close.hour}:${time.close.minute}`;
            let openTime = `${time.open.hour}:${time.open.minute}`;
            return {
                closeTime: closeTime,
                openTime: openTime
            };
        });
        let myHoursList = [];   //this is variable that does not gets changed first time
        hoursList.filter(interval => {
            let start = moment(interval.startTime, "HH:mm")
            let end = moment(interval.endTime, "HH:mm")
            let to = moment(timeLapses[0].closeTime, "HH:mm")
            let from = moment(timeLapses[0].openTime, "HH:m")
            return from <= start && end <= to
        })

        setCustomHourList(myHoursList);  //updating State Here

         }
```

Finally Here is the funtion for changing date

```
    const _handleChangeDate = async (date: any) => {
        handleChangeDate(date);
        date = new Date(date).getDay();
        await getHoursList(date);
    }
```

Comment: "more than 50 objects" is absolutely nothing, that's clearly not the problem, don't worry about it. Anyway, please provide more info: you talk about the useState() but it isn't even present in the code sample; also, provide an example of how it is actually used (i.e. is it in a useEffect?)

Comment: I just edited the question and Added more details...let me know if you need anything?

Comment: Hmm still not clear enough IMO. Since _handleChangeDate is the function that triggers the fetch and the update, it would be useful to understand how/where it is invoked.
However, by looking at the code and the description, either _handleChangeDate isn't called or the hoursList.filter returns an empty array the first time. I can't guess anything else

Comment: I tried to generate a random number and logged on the console. It generates random number every time but again the issue is  **myHoursList** dones not gets updated

Comment: So you're telling you're sure _handleChangeDate is called... but what does the `hoursList.filter(...)` return? If the first time it returns an empty array or even if it throws, that's the problem.
(also note that on the edited code you're missing the `myHoursList = ` on the filter)

Comment: @GiovanniLondero no it does not throws empty array.. it throws same old value...But main issue is when I change date twice then the values from **hoursLists.filter(...)** gets updated but on one time change values from **hoursLists.filter(...)** does not changed

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to tell then. But still, what do you mean *hoursList.filter(...)* returns the same old value? It doesn't have anything to do with the old value, every time it creates a new array and the filter isn't even invoked on the same variable (it's invoked on hoursList, but the state is in customHourList). Multiple things bug me, please check variables names again, or extend the example, as I fear there might be some issues. Where does "hoursList" come from anyway?

Comment: If you can provide an example on stackblitz or codesandbox or something like that, with the issue reproducible, it would be helpful.